# Как присвоить переменной лямбда функцию без использования auto

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражение

Например есть лямбда которая возвращает какое-либо значение из функции

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto f = []()
    {
        std::cout << "Lambda has been invoked" << std::endl;
        return 10;
    };
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

Там указано ключевое слово `auto`. Но как мне указать определенный тип потому что вот так не работает

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int f = []() //поменял auto ｙｆいんｔ
    {
        std::cout << "Lambda has been invoked" << std::endl;
        return 10;
    };
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

Простите за глупый вопрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int (*f)() = []()->int
    {
        std::cout << "Lambda has been invoked" << std::endl;
        return 10;
    };
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

Соответственно если вам нужны аргументы:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int (*f)(char) = [](char c)->int
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        return 10;
    };
    std::cout << f('a') << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: А что конкретно делают вторые скобки? `int (*f)()`

Comment: А все понял, спасибо

Comment: Как можно будет, приму

Answer (score 3):

Указатели на функции, предложенные @uber42, будут работать только если у лямбды пустой список захвата `[]`.

```
auto  a    = []{return 42;}; // Компилируется
int (*b)() = []{return 42;}; // Компилируется
int x = 42;
auto  с    = [x](){return x;}; // Компилируется
int (*d)() = [x](){return x;}; // Ошибка: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'int (*)()' in initialization
```

---

Типы ламбд - это **не** указатели на функии.

Каждая лямбда имеет свой *анонимный* тип, который по сути является классом с перегруженным оператором `()`.

Лямбду можно преобразовать к указателю на функцию только если у нее пустой список захвата `[]`.

Обратите внимание на слова "*анонимный* тип" - раз у типа нет имени, то его не получится указать явно, и придется использовать `auto`.

---

Можно использовать `std::function` (или похожий класс-обертку), который работает всегда, независимо от наличия списка захвата:

```
std::function<int()> e = [x](){return x;}; // Компилируется
```

Однако нужно понимать, что `std::function` занимает больше памяти, чем тип, определенный `auto`, и вызывается медленнее (или уж точно не быстрее).

Поэтому `auto` предпочтительнее.